# Program to find a pair with highest product from array of integers

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have written a code for this. But is there any easier method or function specifically in NumPy?

I tried this code:

```
ar = np.array([4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 0, 8])
prod = 0
ar1 = 0
for x in ar:
  i = np.where(ar == x)[0][0]
  for y in ar:
    if y == ar[i]:
      continue
    else:
      ar1 = x * y  #storing highest product
      if ar1 > prod:
        prod = ar1
        y1 = y
        x1 = x
print([x1, y1])
```

Comment: Isn't this equivalent to finding the maximum two elements in the array?

Comment: You should specify the task and show a full example. We shouldn't need to read your code to know the task, and the code can't be trusted to be correct anyway.

Comment: @DaniMesejo Right. I didn't thought in that way thanks.

Comment: @KellyBundy I have specified the task in the heading. Sorry if I miscommunicated.

Comment: @DaniMesejo ... unless there are negative numbers in the list, e.g. `1, 2, 3, -1000, -2000`

Comment: You fail input [1,2,3,3], you print the pair [2,3] but the pair [3,3] has a larger product.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the two maximum numbers and the two minimum numbers and comparing their products should give the right answer.

```
ar = np.array([4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 0, 8])
ar.sort()
a, b = ar[-2:], ar[:2]
if np.prod(a) > np.prod(b):
    print(a)
else:
    print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Deliberately not an efficient way to do this, but it uses Numpy:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 0, 8], dtype=object)
o = np.outer(x, x).flatten()
a = np.argsort(o)
print(o[a][-2:]) 
'''
[56 64]
'''
```

Please clarify your question if this is not what you are asking for.

Comment: I  was looking for something like this. I want to find pairs whose product is max. So the answer should be 7, 8. Sorry for not clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @DaniMesejo I got the answer:

```
ar = np.array([4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 0, 8])
ar.sort()
print(ar[-2:])
```

Comment: If this solution meets all your requirements `np.partition(ar, -2)[-2:]` is ~`log n` times faster for larger arrays.

Comment: Consider what happens in the case that your list contains negative numbers, in that the product of two negative numbers is positive (and potentially the best solution). See comments to your original question.